# How to make one child the default one when using <Outlet /> in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, outlet

I have the following route setup in `App.js`

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomeLayout />}>
      <Route path="/my-course" element={<MyCourse />} />
      <Route path="/all-course" element={<AllCourse />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

inside `HomeLayout` there is a

1. sidebar that containes link to other routes
2. `<Outlet>` to hold the contetnt of the other three routes

the problem is when I access `/` only the sidebar is shown but I want `MyCourses` to be the default one and displayed on accessing `/`

I have tried two solutions

1.

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<HomeLayout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<MyCourse />} />
      <Route path="/my-course" element={<MyCourse />} />
      <Route path="/all-course" element={<AllCourse />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

on this one the the content displays but the url doesn't change (the url doesn't change to `localhost:3000/my-course` it stays on `localhost:3000` )

2.

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/my-courses" />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<MyCourse />} />
      <Route path="/my-course" element={<MyCourse />} />
      <Route path="/all-course" element={<AllCourse />} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

in this cases (on the above case as well) when the I am on `/dashboard` and hit refresh the page goes to `/my-course`

how can i make `my-course` the default child and preserve path on refresh